# gridview highlighting current row

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Is there a built-in method of highlighting the currently selected row in a gridview?

Each row in my gridview has a button (via a buttonField).  When the user presses this button, the background color changes...I do it like this:

```
Protected Sub gvTransferOwner_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvTransferOwner.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim selectedRow As GridViewRow = gvTransferOwner.Rows(index)
        selectedRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#ffcccc")
    End If
End Sub
```

This highlights the row, but once the user presses the button in another row, it still retains that color in all previously-pressed rows.

Is there a way so that only one row at a time(the currently selected row) is highlighted?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a global variable to store the index of the row that is being selected, you can change that row back to the original color whenever a new row is selected.

```
Dim previousSelected As Integer 'global variable to store the last selected index
Protected Sub gvTransferOwner_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvTransferOwner.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim selectedRow As GridViewRow = gvTransferOwner.Rows(previousSelected)
        selectedRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#ffffff") 'change it back to original color
        selectedRow = gvTransferOwner.Rows(index)
        selectedRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#ffcccc") 'change the color of the new row
        previousSelected = index
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The gridview has a SelectedIndexChanged event as well as has a [GridView.SelectedRow Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx) which you can use in conjunction with @jonhopkins' answer.

Answer (score 2):

I do it in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and it works for me.

```
GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Dim previousSelected As Integer

```
        If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
            previousSelected = GetVal(ViewState("previousSelected"))
            Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
            Dim selectedRow As GridViewRow = grvOptionset.Rows(previousSelected)
            selectedRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#ffffff") 'change it back to original color
            selectedRow = grvOptionset.Rows(index)
            selectedRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#ffcccc") 'change the color of the new row
            ViewState("previousSelected") = index
        End If
```

Comment: alright, now delete one answer, and add some special Tapan language for quality

Comment: how to write this type of code like Net & Clean. Please Tell me

Comment: highlight the block and hit the squiggly { } thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim previousSelected As Integer 'global variable to store the last selected index
Protected Sub gvTransferOwner_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvTransferOwner.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
         previousSelected = ViewState("previousSelected")
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim selectedRow As GridViewRow = gvTransferOwner.Rows(previousSelected)
        selectedRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#ffffff") 'change it back to original color
        selectedRow = gvTransferOwner.Rows(index)
        selectedRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#ffcccc") 'change the color of the new row
         ViewState("previousSelected") = index
    End If
End Sub
```