# ASP GridView select row by index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got `GridView` element. I highlight selected row with some color. But the problem is when I select new element the elements which were selected before are still highlighted. Here the method and stuff

cs

```
protected void CompanyGV_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // CompanyGV.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
    GridViewRow row = CompanyGV.SelectedRow;
    row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#BCED91");                   
}
```

aspx

```
<asp:GridView ForeColor="Black"  Height="400px" ID="CompanyGV" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"  runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="companies_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataCompanyList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CompanyGV_SelectedIndexChanged"> 

                             <Columns>

                                 <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" SelectText="Select" ShowSelectButton="True" />

                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="№" DataField="companies_id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="companies_id"/>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="companies_name" HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="companies_name" />
                            </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

I want to restrict multiple selection and I want to highlight selected element only! IS there are methods to chagne color for whole `GridView`? Or is there are way to select row by index and go through rows?

I tried to write smth like this but I getting `stack overflow` error message

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= CompanyGV.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
 {

      CompanyGV.SelectRow(i);
      CompanyGV.SelectedRow.Cells[i].BackColor =System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
}
```

Comment: why dont you use default Select command column in the gridview, using it, you dont need to handle the styling manually, and it will also guarantee to apply the selected style to latest selected row only

Comment: @UsmanWaheed oh well, how can I use it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13568173/2763709 please refer this

Comment: possible duplicate of [gridview highlighting current row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567859/gridview-highlighting-current-row)

Comment: do it on client side instead.

Comment: @TheDictator yeah I guess you right

Comment: @TheDictator but how coul I get the index in C#?

Comment: @AshwiniVerma I am not as familiar as I'd wish to with js  :/

Comment: @DanilGholtsman u can get it by same using `e.commandarguement`

Comment: @TheDictator seems like I can't http://i.imgur.com/n026DPN.png

Comment: @DanilGholtsman see my answer below.

Comment: @DanilGholtsman are u doing that inside `SelectedIndexChanged`??

Comment: @TheDictator of course!

Comment: @DanilGholtsman then it must have to come

Comment: @TheDictator but it doesn't :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer it at client side. Try this code

**JQuery**

```
<script src="~/Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#CompanyGV tr').click(function () {
            $('#<%=CompanyGV.ClientID%> tr').removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.selected{
  background-color:Green !important;
}
```

Comment: I added into this ` <script type ="text/javascript" src="Content/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js">
         </script>`

Comment: that's wrong. I edidited the answer, and make sure your jquery liberary loaded correctly in the page. see using firebug.

Answer (score 0):

in design view, go to grid views common tasks, then click Edit columns, then use command field node to select Select column a screenshot is here:

[Image](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-IfmEoZ6tjhM/TbPQ1qJWlWI/AAAAAAAAAP8/GClQKNItWZw/s1600/GridView+Data+Control+asp.net+Example+.png)

Comment: Well, I found options but where are such properties?
http://i.imgur.com/mGQo5lg.png